# MySQL UNION query with condition

Tags: php, mysql

I got 2 columns festivals and events, like

festival

```
id  |   name     | modified_date
-----------------------------------
12  | fest 1     |  2012-03-14 17:45:40
13  | fest 2     |  2012-03-14 17:45:40
15  | fest 4     |  2012-03-14 17:45:40
11  | fest 5     |  2012-03-14 17:45:40
```

events

```
id  |   name     | modified_date
-----------------------------------
14  | envt 1     |  2012-03-14 17:45:40
15  | envt 2     |  2012-03-14 17:45:40
16  | envt 4     |  2012-03-14 17:45:40
17  | envt 5     |  2012-03-14 17:45:40
```

There is a page in my application showing Recent Updates , and by clicking on each list it will redirect to corresponding event or festival.

For this I had the following query

```
select id,name,modified_date from events
UNION
select id,name,modified_date from festival
order by modified_date desc
```

This will return a table like

```
id  |   name     |  modified_date
-------------------------------------
12  | fest 1     |  2012-03-14 17:45:40
13  | fest 2     |  2012-03-14 17:45:40
--------------------------------------------
```

But my question is I need one more column in out put for understanding that row represents a event or festival .. Something like ths

```
id  |   name     |  modified_date         |  type
---------------------------------------------------
12  | fest 1     |  2012-03-14 17:45:40   |  festival
15  | evnt 2     |  2012-03-14 17:45:40   |  event
```

Please help
Thanks in advance

Comment: You might want to use UNION ALL instead of UNION, because it's usually faster if you know that your result sets don't overlap (UNION requires the RDBMS to perform a DISTINCT internally).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
select id, name, modified_date, 'event' as type
from events 

UNION 

select id, name, modified_date, 'festival' as type
from festival 
order by modified_date desc
```

Comment: @Phil You know what they say... to win, you have to be smart, be fast, or cheat.  Since I haven't found a good way to cheat yet, I just focus on fast.

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick

```
select id,name,modified_date, 'event' AS type from events
UNION
select id,name,modified_date, 'festival' AS type from festival order by modified_date desc
```